# Configurable product not visible in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I imported configure product as CSV files and created its associated products using 'quick simple product creation' and set website and category. But its not displaying in the front end.

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi. have you checked visibility of that product?

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure configurable product attributes

1- Visibilty= Catalog,Search

2- Status= Enabled

3- Asosiated product should be in stock quantity at least 1

4- Clear Cache and reindex

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to admin. Go to catalog > manage products > open that configurable product
2. Check the status and visibility as enable, catalog,search
3. Assign product to Main website then clear cache.